# if variable equals else

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

Been trying all different ways of getting this to work. It's a Google spreadsheet script.
I get a error if a currency USDT comes up as there is no market BTC-USDT, it is USDT-BTC.
So I'm trying to make it set pair to altcoin+"-BTC" if the currency is USDT, Have tried multiple ways reading up different ways sometimes all I get it to do is USDT-BTC all the time, no other options.
 This way I just get a error but it gives a better idea with what I'm trying to do.

```
for (var i = 1; i < currencyarray.length; i++) {
        var altcoin = currencyarray[i][0];
        {
        if (altcoin = "USDT") {
          var pair = altcoin+"-BTC";
          else {
            var pair = "BTC-"+altcoin;
}
          //sheet.getRange((1+i), 3).setValue(pair);
          //sheet.getRange((1+i), 4).setValue(currencyarray[i][1]);
          sheet.getRange((1+i), 5).setValue(currencyarray[i][1]);
        }
}
```

opps, sorry forgot extra =. Have changed it a little but when it gets to USDT it does BTC-BTC not USDT-BTC, Sorry I'm not a full time coder, try to teach myself.

```
for (var i = 1; i < currencyarray.length; i++) {
var altcoin = currencyarray[i][0];
{
  if (altcoin == "USDT") 
    pair = altcoin+"-BTC";
  else pair = "BTC-"+altcoin;

}


  sheet.getRange((1+i), 5).setValue(currencyarray[i][1]);
  var lastprice = bittrexGetlastprice(pair);
  var value = (currencyarray[i][1]*lastprice);
  sheet.getRange((1+i), 5).setValue(value);
}
```

Comment: It looks like it's javascript

Comment: http://javascriptisnotjava.io

Comment: `=` is assignment. Use `==` instead: `if (altcoin == "USDT")`. (Also, this is JavaScript, not Java).

Answer (score 1):

In this line

```
if (altcoin = "USDT") {
```

You set altcoin to USDT, which counts as a truthy value, so the body of this if always runs. Use `==` when comparing

```
if (altcoin == "USDT") {
```

Answer (score 0):

This works,

use `==` in `if` condition.